# Tkinter GUI does not respond

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to run a program that asks a user for a directory which which they will move their files to.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk

class Unzip():
    def __init__(self):
        #  initialising the screen name, size title
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('650x550')
        root.title("Move Files")
        root.resizable(0, 0)
        root.configure(bg='#002060')

        # Initialising the frame to insert our widget
        top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#002060')
        button_top = tk.Frame(root, bg='#002060')
        button_bottom = tk.Frame(root, bg='#002060')
        footer_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#002060')

        top_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both')
        button_top.pack(side='top', fill='both')
        button_bottom.pack(side='top', fill='both')
        footer_frame.pack(side='bottom', fill='both')

        # Setting the title name
        label_title = tk.Label(top_frame, text='Move Files', font='Arial 36 bold', fg='#948a54',
                               bg='#002060', pady=60)
        label_title.pack(side='top')


# call button to get output file
        output_file = ttk.Button(button_bottom, text='Choose location to save files', width=25, command=self.output_path)
        output_file.pack(side='left', padx=(120, 10), pady=10)

        root.mainloop()

# Get output directory
    def output_path(self):
        self.output_file_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Unzip()
```

The problem is that when you run the program and try to run the `output_file` button, the program will not be responding. I decided to use the `self` because I wanted it to be accessible to other instance methods that I want to create that will use the directory `output_path`.

Comment: The code works on my system. Maybe its taking time for the `filedialog` to pop up

Answer (score 1):

So what exactly are you expecting? Your program does respond, but it is not supposed to do anything with the information.
Try

```
def output_path(self):
    self.output_file_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(self.output_file_dir)
```

Do you see what happens?
Maybe example 2 from this link can help you: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/95888/tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory

Comment: I removed all the other instance methods. It is supposed to get that directory and pass it to another instance to be used. I keep getting this: https://imgur.com/a/pXALkfj